# how to change url for edit in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

I have an edit page, I have used resource controller for it. Everytime the page redirects from edit  `(../members/16/edit)` it continues with the edit page url `(../members/16/members)`.  [where it should only take `../members`]
How can I remove/change url for edit.

Route

```
Route::resource('members', MemberController::class);
```

edit function

```
 public function edit(Member $members,$id)
    {
        $members = Member::find($id);
        return view('edit', compact('members'));
    }
    public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $members = Member::find($id);
    $members->name = $request->name;
    $members->save();
    return view('committee')->with('success', 'Member Updated successfully');
}



  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-success" title="Edit NewsRoom Details" 
                href="'.route("members.edit",[$members->id]).'"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should identify what you are passing example:

```
<a href="{{ route('members.edit', ['members' => $members->id, 'id' => $id]) }}">...</a>
```

Your update method is not redirecting anywhere, it is simply loading a different view, the correct way to do it is:

```
public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $members = Member::find($id);
    $members->name = $request->name;
    $members->save();
    //return view('committee')->with('success', 'Member Updated successfully');
    return redirect()->route('members.committee')->with('success', 'Member Updated successfully');
}
```

Comment: Edit function works fine, it is updating but while redirecting after updating the url does not change

Comment: @PreethiShetty oh okay, i changed my answer, you need to actually "REDIRECT" somewhere after update is success, you can create a named route to do this.